# In postgresql, when the row exists, show the row and add an additional column. And always show one row even though it doesn't exist

Tags: sql, postgresql

I mean Postgresql specifically.

For example, I have a table as below:

```
client    action     date    
 A      search     2016-08-22
 A      search     2016-08-21 
 A      search     2016-08-20
 B      search     2016-06-22
 B       Ads       2016-07-10 
 B       Ads       2016-08-20
```

I am looking each client separately. If I look for client 'A' and 'Ads' in action, I want to return a table like:

```
client   action   status      last_date
 A        --    no existed     --
```

If I look for client 'B' and 'Ads' in action,

```
client   action    status    last_date
 B        Ads     existed    2016-08-20
```

I tried `case when`, but it will return several rows until appearance of `action = 'Ads'`

I tried `where action like 'Ads'`, but it won't return anything if there is no such action for a client.

I want to always show a row to visualize the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH cteCross AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT client, c.SearchText
    FROM
       TableName t
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT 'Ads' as SearchText) c
    WHERE t.client = 'A'
)

SELECT
    c.client
    ,t.action
    ,CASE WHEN t.client IS NOT NULL THEN 'existed' ELSE 'No Existed' END as status
    ,MAX(date) AS last_date
FROM
    cteCross c
    LEFT JOIN TableName t
    ON c.client = t.client
    AND c.SearchText = t.action
GROUP BY
    c.client
    ,t.action
    ,CASE WHEN t.client IS NOT NULL THEN 'existed' ELSE 'No Existed' END
```

You have to know what you do not know....

So to do that you have to first understand all of the possible combinations that could exist.  That is why you take a cross join of the value you want to search for and the DISTINCT clients.

Next you join back to the original table to see what exists and what doesn't.

If you take out the WHERE in the cteCross it will give you results for all clients the way you want them.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `union all` with the "not found" row last, and pick only the first row:

```
select * from (
    select client, action, 'existed' status, date
    from mytable
    where client = 'A' and action = 'Ads'
    union all
    select 'A', null, 'no existed', null
) x
order by action -- nulls order last by default
limit 1
```

The first row will be the found row if one exists, and the dummy row otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The query runs smoothly. I added order by action, date desc instead in order to get the latest date.

Comment: @zed did it work? Was it fast? If not, what happened?

Comment: Can this query be inlined function? Create or Replace function fn_tb1 (client character)  returns table (client character, action character, status character, date date)  AS $$  Begin  return query  select * from ( select client, action, 'existed' status, date from mytable ...........limit 1 End $$ Language plpgsq1